# scroll the content inside the div with fixed position using browser/page scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[image]

I have some div's with `position:fixed` all around the page. 
one of that div has little more long content.

my aim is that I want to scroll the content inside that box, using the main browser/page scroll-bar. **(its not normal `overflow:auto` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sBQ3m/10/))** 
this is the exact situation 
http://s7.postimage.org/d6xl1u9mz/sample.jpg

is any plugin available ?

Comment: its not my decision, I'm forced to do that badly :(

Comment: And what about the mousewheel? :)

Comment: Sounds like you could put the content on the main body, and `position:fixed` everything on top of it. We can't really give you anything specific without actual code, though.

Comment: @roXon its to be works like the normal page scroll with scrollbar and mouse wheel

Comment: this is the exact situation 
http://s7.postimage.org/d6xl1u9mz/sample.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's possible. I've created a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EAk7y/5/) which does the trick. It's not perfect, but you can develope it further... Also this snippet works only with modern browsers, but is easy to fix for older IEs too. Core code below.

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var content = document.getElementById('contentwrapper'),
        dimdiv = document.getElementById('scrollingheight'),
        wrapHeight = document.getElementById('fixed').offsetHeight,
        scroller = function () {
            content.style.top = -(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + 5 + 'px';
            return;
        };
    dimdiv.style.minHeight = (content.scrollHeight - wrapHeight + 2 * 5) + 'px';
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
    return; 
}
```

CSS:

```
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    left: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#contentwrapper {
    max-width: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
#scrollingheight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollingheight"></div>
<div id="fixed">
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice, that *all* content in the `body`, but `#scrollingheight`, must be fixed. Constant `5` is related to `#contentwrapper`'s `top` value.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowledge of your HTML:

```
<body>
    <section id="bodyContent"></section>
    <header></header>
    <section id="lSide"></section>
    <section id="rSide"></section>
</body>
```

```css
#bodyContent {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 90px 45px 0px 105px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(page_background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
header, #lSide, #rSide {
    position: fixed;
}
header {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-image: url(page_background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#lSide {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 105px;
    padding: 90px 0 0 0;
}
#rSide {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    padding: 90px 0 0 0;
}
```

This will force the contents of `#bodyContent` to sit inside the opening between the various border elements, and it will cause any overflow to trigger a scrollbar on the `body` element as you desire. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wJmBj/1/)

Comment: It seems you've beaten me and roXon : ). Only annoying `width: 100%;` for `#bodyContent` needs to fix, now it always hides a part of the content. +1 anyway...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to with hiding part of the content. In my testing, all the content is visible (unless scrolled up and away).

Comment: Outch... it seems to do it only in Firefox... FF needs `-moz-box-sizing`

Comment: Oh, that's my bad. Forgot to put the vendor prefixed version in there. Editing in a moment. New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wJmBj/3/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK **you cannot do that.**
 
At least not without some wicked JS trickery.
`Why?` cause you cannot force the browser's default scrollbar height (make it smaller) to embrace some content that is inside a totally different area than the `html, body` (document).

 My suggestion is that you build a custom scrollbar, calculate the height of your nice `overflow hidden` area, add it to the *scrollable ratio* calculation.